# Get .mp4 source and poster image from Vine Id (PHP)

Tags: php, html, url, vine

How to get video.mp4 from vine url?

Example:

from `https://vine.co/v/hnVVW2uQ1Z9`

I need `http://.../*.mp4` and `http://.../*.jpg`

Script what I need use this page [vinebed.com](http://vinebed.com/)

(In PHP)

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. if you check the source of a vine video from vine.co you'll see the meta tags. and you should see twitter:player:stream. By using php you can extract that information specifically and use it like a variable.

```
<?php
function vine( $id )
{
        $vine = file_get_contents("http://vine.co/v/{$id}");
        preg_match('/property="twitter:player:stream" content="(.*?)"/', $vine, $matches);
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        return ($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;

}
?>
```

And to set an `$id` you will need to create a function that will either **A**) Automatically read a vine video id by url and you can display it like this `<?php echo vine('bv5ZeQjY35'); ?>` or **B**) Just set a vine video id and display as is.

Hope this helps as it's worked for me just fine.